# What is the reason behind reloading the entire page when changing tenants?

Tags: angular, typescript, aspnetboilerplate

I would like to know the reasoning behind reloading the entire login page when a tenant is changed:

```
save(): void {
    if (!this.tenancyName) {
        abp.multiTenancy.setTenantIdCookie(undefined);
        this.close();
        location.reload();
        return;
    }
}
```

And then when reloading, `init()` function is called in **app-session.service.ts**:

```
init(): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
        this._sessionService.getCurrentLoginInformations().toPromise().then((result: GetCurrentLoginInformationsOutput) => {
            this._application = result.application;
            this._user = result.user;
            this._tenant = result.tenant;

            resolve(true);
        }, (err) => {
            reject(err);
        });
    });
}
```

which does not make sense to me because in the `GetCurrentLoginInformationsOutput` function, current local session is being updated with various API access tokens that are then again being updated when the user successfully logs in.

Currently, I changed the logic behind swapping tenants and I removed the `location.reload()` part. The reasoning behind that was to speed up the response time of the application.

My biggest question is, do I lose any valuable information when not calling the reload page part and will the application work normally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenant may have different language and other settings. Reloading the page resets the state etc.

> but if I update those settings after login, doesn't the reload page part seem redundant?

The landing page needs some settings (e.g. language) too.